# Hyperledger activity not visible on docker logs (LinuxOne)

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm running a blockchain setup (Peer, CouchDB instance, orderer and CA) on a LinuxOne cloud instance (Suse) as outlined here: https://github.com/IBM/hyperledger-fabric-on-linux-one

I'm using Hyperledger composer to deploy a sample application on the blockchain, and trying to follow it on the Suse instance using the docker log command as follows:

```
linux1@fab2~> docker logs -f 17cf990f8ff6
```

The last argument is the container ID from the output of docker ps -a corresponding to hyperledger/fabric-peer:s390x-1.0.4

I'm unable to see any chaincode activity in the logs as I add a new asset or execute a transaction. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any information

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker logs -f ca.blocks.xyz.com
```